# Creating a HTTP post with arduino

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to create a HTTP post with arduino Duemilanove (Very similar to Arduino UNO) without the Arduino Ethernet Shield?
I have found tutorials, but all of them use the Ethernet Shield or the arduino YUN, and I just have my very simple Arduino Duemilanove. 
If it is possible to do a HTTP post with my arduino, can you please explain me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino has to connect to the internet somewhere, and the Ethernet shield handles doing this. If you only want to use the Arduino there isn't much you can do besides implementing your own internet stack from 802.3 to TCP/IP, or trying to find someone who has tried to do this. This might not be possible anyway (I'm not familiar enough with 802.3 to know if an Arduino without the ethernet shield can be programmed to handle it).

Alternatively, if the Arduino can be connected to another machine, you could send information over the serial connection to another computer that does have an internet connection, and have that generate the HTTP post message.